# How to add a string at the end of a list with python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, nested-lists

Hi guys I'm new with python and i would like to add at the n-th term of a list of tuples a new string suppose the following:

```
_list = [('string0', 'string1'),.... ,('stringN', 'stringN-1')]
```

I would like to add another string like this:

```
_list = [('string0', 'string1'),.... ,('stringN', 'stringN-1'),'NEW_STRING']
```

**edited:**

I tried the following with the append method:

```
_list.append('NEW_STRING')

print "this is the updated list",_list
```

Any idea of how to incorporate a new string at the end of a list of n tuples?.

Comment: First, dont use `list` as a veriable name. So why does not your example work, any errros?

Comment: Sorry guys now it works!, thank you. Let me update the question with the correct answer for everybody in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below
.append() should work.

```
list = [('string0', 'string1'),('stringN', 'stringN-1')]
list.append("hello")
print list
```

Answer (score 2):

`list.append` works in-place changing your object (which you shouldn't call `list`).

```
list.append('NEW_STRING')
print list
```

Comment: When i try with this and the other answers it rise the following exception: TypeError'NoneType' obtect is not iterable

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> my_list = ['a','b']
>>> print "hello", my_list.append('c')   
hello None
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

you code will work, the string will be appended, but as append returns None, so it will print None

so to avoid printing None, put append in next line.

Note: using list as variable name is bad practice, as `list` is inbuilt function in python